# MongoDB aggregate to query int64

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregate

Let say my mongodb data store some data with int

1. num: 850531015931
2. num: 860338053336
3. num: 859923992712

Now i would like to query aggregate with regex
those num start with 85, how do i do this with aggregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to convert integer in to string using **$substr** operator than perform **$match** funtion using **$regex** operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project :{numstring : {$substr :["$number",0,12]}}},{$match :{"numstring":{$regex : /^8.5/}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @G.C.Looi, this answer is going to give you incorrect results because of the wrong regular expression (4J41's answer has the right one). Plus, in your example you're actually showing long values, not ints so the length 12 doesn't work for all of the long data range (for ints, it should be 10, actually). Again, 4J41's answer is better here if you really need a regex.

Answer (score 1):

[**$substr**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) can be used in a [**$project**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation) stage to convert the num to a string value. You can then have a [**$match**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#match-aggregation) stage with the regex.

**Project Stage:**

```
{
    $project:{
        numAsString: { $substr : ["$num", 0, -1 ] }
    }
}
```

**Match Stage:**

```
{
    $match : { numAsString: { $regex: /^85.*/ } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be done by regexes, I would like to suggest an alternate method. The problem with regex is that it wont allow you to index elements. Hence as your collection size increases, your queries will become slower and slower.

You can just go for the basics and do the following checks

```
{$or: [
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 85] }, {$lte: ['$num', 85] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 850] }, {$lte: ['$num', 859] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 8500] }, {$lte: ['$num', 8599] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 85000] }, {$lte: ['$num', 85999] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 850000] }, {$lte: ['$num', 859999] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 8500000] }, {$lte: ['$num', 8599999] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 85000000] }, {$lte: ['$num', 85999999] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 850000000] }, {$lte: ['$num', 859999999] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 8500000000] }, {$lte: ['$num', 8599999999] } ]},
    {$and: [ {$gte: ['$num', 85000000000] }, {$lte: ['$num', 85999999999] } ]},
]}
```

Keep doing this till you reach the max possible value in `num`. Sorry for the ugly code, but it should run **faster**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in using a regular expression in your specific case. As the others already pointed out the conversion to a string can be done using [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) but the all it takes for the filtering is a standard equals comparison:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        "firstTwoDigits": { // create a new field called "firstTwoDigits"
            $substr: ["$num", 0, 2] // extract the first two digits only
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "firstTwoDigits": "85" // simple filter
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.